# best practice to add/remove www from a website's address

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

if you go to:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com you'll be redirected to
>   http://stackoverflow.com
>
> http://facebook.com you'll be redirected to http://www.facebook.com

the problem is that if a user **authenticates** to:

http://www.example.com

and after goes to http://example.com he will not be authenticated (because the domain is different, I guess)

I noticed that stackoverflow and facebook redirect to the domain with/without www

anybody knows how this is done ?

Comment: The auth cookie gets set for `.mysite.com` so that subdomains (of which www. is technically one) are also covered.

Comment: Did any of this answer your question, or is there some way we might elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking two different questions:
**Question 1:** How do you redirect to a canonical domain name, ie always add a "www" to www.example.com?
**Answer:**This is dependent on the server that you're using, but on an IIS hosted site (eg, .NET) you would modify the rewrite rules of the website's web.config. On an Apache hosted website (eg, PHP) you would modify the .htaccess file. The specifics of how you write those rules have already been stated in other answers so I won't bother to repost them.
**Question 2:**How do you ensure that a user that's authenticated for "www.example.com" is also authenticated for "example.com"?
**Answer:**Most authentication tokens are stored in a cookie. If that cookie's domain is set to "www.example.com", it will only authenticate for "www.example.com". The key is to set the cookie's domain to ".example.com". Notice the dot before "example" but the lack of a "www" prefix. That allows the cookie to cross all subdomains of "example.com", therefore it would also work for "subdomain1.example.com", etc.

**EDIT:** I just realized there isn't a .net example of redirecting to canonical host with url rewrite, so here's one. The following would be nested inside the system.webServer element of your web.config file in the root directory of your website:

```
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CanonicalHostName">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

**EDIT2:** To address Chuck's comment below:
If you've got subdomains that you don't want to share authentication with, then force your visitors of (www.)example.com to either always use www, or always be www-less with an .htaccess rewrite rule like Swadq's/Vyktor's (if you're on linux) or a web.config rewrite rule like mine (if your on windows). That way users won't even have the option of being authenticated for the domain you're redirecting them away from. Set your authentication cookie domain to www.example.com if you're using www, or just plain example.com if you're going www-less. 
That will work even with subdomains with which you don't want to share authentication.

Comment: There is subdomains, and they should be treated as different sites, no shared authentication, is this code going to work this way ?

Answer (score 2):

Modify .htaccess to add a redirect to your chosen subdomain. All cookies should be set from this domain, it should be impossible to actually use the other domain.

Here:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`
```

That will always redirect to www. The rule will have to be changed to redirect to the main domain.

Alternatively you could use PHP to make a 301 (Permanent) redirect, before sending headers (by outputting html).

```
<?PHP
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.domain.com" ); 
?>
```

If you want to use Asp.net, as you have tagged the post, add this to your index page:

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.domain.com");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use web.config to rewrite in much the same way that you can use .htaccess. The .net solution provided is not adequate as it requires them to hit the homepage first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), [see example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-redirect-domaincom-to-wwwdomaincom/) (first gogole result after: `apache redirect`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact method depends on whether you use IIS, Apache or something else.  But if you are using IIS (which I assume since you tagged the question asp.net) you can take the mod_rewrite code suggested by Vyktor and use the Import mod_rewrite Rules in IIS Manager to convert them to something IIS compatible.

Comment: I use asp.net hosting, and my application is on asp.net-mvc